# How to parse the data obtained by using CURL to get DL?

Tags: php, curl

I want to show list of journals and their abbreviation like:

Journal Name, Abbreviation

I am getting the data I need from :
 http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/D_abrvjt.html
So I am running the following:

$ch = curl_init();

```
//Set options
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL =>           'http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/A_abrvjt.html'
 ));
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 $data=json_decode($result, true);
 //!End function, make_call
```

But now what it shows me is the whole page, but as I said I only need the name of the journals(dt) and the abbreviation (dd). So How can I pars the result?

Comment: Use an HTML DOM Parser.
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ take a look at the scraping example.

Comment: so if I use it, do I still have to use curl?

Comment: No you don't. Use the file_get_html() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML DOM parsing via [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
Scraping method ...

```
<?php

Function Scraper($file, $cnt = NULL) {
    /*
      @param $file, url or path/file
      @param $cnt, (number of results to list) empty for all, or number
    */
    require_once('PATH/TO/simple_html_dom.php');
    //set_time_limit(0); // uncomment for large files
    $result = array();

    // Create DOM from URL
    $html = file_get_html($file);
    IF ($html) {
        IF (empty($cnt)) { $cnt = count($html->find('DT')); }

        foreach($html->find('DL') as $dl) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
                $dt = $dl->find('DT', $i)->plaintext;
                $dd = $dl->find('DD', $i)->plaintext;
                $result[] = array(trim($dt) => trim($dd));
            }

        }
    }

    return $result;

}

$array = Scraper('http://somesite.com/page.html');
print_r($array);
?>
```

Example output ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [D H LAWRENCE REVIEW] => D H LAWRENCE REV
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [D-D EXCITATIONS IN TRANSITION-METAL OXIDES] => SPRINGER TR MOD PHYS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DADOS-REVISTA DE CIENCIAS SOCIAIS] => DADOS-REV CIENC SOC
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DAEDALUS] => DAEDALUS
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [DAEDALUS] => DAEDALUS-US
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [DAGHESTAN AND THE WORLD OF ISLAM] => SUOMAL TIED TOIM SAR
        )

)
```

**Updated example specific to user350082's issue ...**

The definition lists DT and DD tags were not closed resulting in the dd being included in the find('dt') result.

```
<DT>D H LAWRENCE REVIEW<B><DD>  D H LAWRENCE REV</B>
<DT>D-D EXCITATIONS IN TRANSITION-METAL OXIDES<B><DD>   SPRINGER TR MOD PHYS</B>
etc. etc. etc.
```

Updated Function ...

```
Function Scraper($file, $cnt = NULL) {

    /*
      @param $file, url or path/file
      @param $cnt, (number of results to list) empty for all, or number
    */
    require_once('PATH/TO/simple_html_dom.php');
    //set_time_limit(0); // uncomment for large files
    $result = array();

    // Create DOM from URL
    $html = file_get_html($file);
    IF ($html) {

        foreach($html->find('DL') as $dl) {

            IF (empty($cnt)) { $cnt = count($html->find('DT')); } // set count if null
            for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {

                $dd = $dl->find('DD', $i)->plaintext;

                $dt = $dl->find('DT', $i)->innertext; // dt with html tags, easier for removing dd duplication
                $dt = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$dt); // remove extra whitespace, tabs etc.

                // strip DD text duplication from DT
                IF (($pos = strrpos($dt ,$dd)) !== false) {
                    $strlen = strlen($dd);
                    $dt = substr_replace($dt, "", $pos, $strlen);
                }

                $dt = strip_tags($dt); // remove html tags
                IF (empty($dt)) { $dt = $dd; } // make sure dt is not empty

                $result[] = array(trim($dt) => trim($dd));

            }

        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, But I am having a small problem, I do not know why but in the output the  <dt> data is repeated 2 times. So I tried to only find <dd>form  the website and display them, but it shows both <dd> and<dt>. I do not know hwy, but when it want to find <dt> tags from the websites, it pulls both<dt> and <dd>. Do you know what may be the problem?

Comment: it's because the <dt> and <dd> tags are not closed. View the source and you'll see <DT>D H LAWRENCE REVIEW<B><DD>D H LAWRENCE REV</B>

To get the correct results you need to do a little more work. I can post an update of what I did for your specific case if you need.

Comment: updated post with a new function specific to your situation. Please mark as answered.